# ArcGIS Pro 2.1 models cannot be exported as Python code! What can I do besides clicking on each individual geoprocessing history item?

Tags: python-3.x

ArcGIS Pro does not allow saving / exporting of a model constructed with Model Builder as a Python script. The only way I can circumvent this limitation is to click on each individual geoprocessing history item, but, as you can imagine, it is not very efficient to do so. This makes me want to run back to QGIS... Any suggestions? They will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This probably isn't the best place to ask this question. Stackoverflow is designed to solve specific coding problems. Have you tried contacting ESRI support?

Comment: It would also fare better at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Mikey, yes.  I have reached out to our agency's relations support within Esri and they are working on a solution.

Comment: PolyGeo, is it possible to transfer my question?  Or do I have to delete and resubmit?

Comment: You could flag moderators here and ask for migration but nowadays I think most modes prefer deletion and then posting on preferred site.